# Брать значения из другого листа в гугл таблицах

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Если использую формулу ='Бисквит'!L16       , значение не подтягивается, так как в ячейке L16 в листе Бисквит находится формула. Как сделать так, чтобы подтягивалась не формула, а значение ячейки(результат)

Comment: Когда вы смотрите на ячейку L16 листа 'Бисквит' вы в ней видете формулу или результат? Если там результат то проблем быть не должно. Попробуйте так `=$Бисквит.L16`, а вообще вводите `=` переходите на лист, кликаете на ячейку

Comment: Что-то не то... Или объясняете криво, или в ячейках что-то кривое :) Если в *L16* рабочая  формула, то она возвращает либо значение, либо ошибку, либо пустую строку. И другая формула, которая  ссылается на *L16*, вернет именно это. Возможная проблема: ячейка, в которую вводится формула `='Бисквит'!L16`, имеет текстовый формат. Изменить формат на нужный и еще раз ввести формулу

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже, что у вас включено отображение формул на листе, по крайней мере только с такими вводными я смог добиться такого результата без изысков.
Для решения проблемы попробуйте нажать Ctrl и ё(` в английской раскладке) или же Вид-Показать-Формулы.